# AS3 Flash SWF File Versioning

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash, versioning

I've looked all over online and can't seem to find a way to put a version number in a swf file. We need to know which version of the swf file we have on different machines, so we had thought of maybe writing a file if it does not exist to the swf directory, containing the swf version number. We are not using Flex and as3, so that's not going to work since we can't write to the disk. So i've been looking around and haven't been able to find where we might specify the file version of our swf to something like "14.06.30".

Is there a way we might be able to set the version of our swf file?

We've thought about using a key press to display a version number, but we don't want to do that because the swf can load in other swf's where keypresses might mean something else. This would be a last resort.

Comment: Couldn't you just add meta data on the file itself?

Comment: Also, unless you're stopping propagation of the event, you can have multiple keyboard event listeners that run together.

Comment: @LDMediaServices your right, that was actually what i was looking for in the first place. We got it covered though using the context menu, which will work just as well, possibly even better since they don't have to find the swf file or close it if its running

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For version numbering in the swf, we use a compile constant http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7abd.html. For example: -define+==CONFIG::VersionString,'{svn version}' With Flash builder you can add this to your additional compiler settings, or set this variable in your Continuous build script. In your actionscript you can read this var with 'CONFIG::VersionString'.

We add this version number to the context menu in the swf (right click menu).

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;

public class Test extends Sprite
{
    public function Test()
    {
        super();
        addVersionToContextMenu();

    }

    private function addVersionToContextMenu () : void
    {
        var item:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem("Version: " + CONFIG::VersionString);
        var items:Array = this.contextMenu.customItems;
        items.push(item);
        this.contextMenu.customItems = items;
    }
}
```

}

If you right click on the swf it looks like:

[image]

Comment: I've actually solved the problem by adding a global constant for the version number, and adding an item to the top of the right click context menu. We didn't do anything with the compile options, but i'll mark this as the answer because its pretty much the same thing we did to solve the problem. thanks

Comment: @iedoc ... But doesn't this type of solution leave you at the same point as your previous keypress solution? quoting: `but we don't want to do that because the swf can load in other swf's where keypresses might mean something else`. Well what happens when its loaded into a parent SWF with its own context menu too? Which one will show up? Just saying...

Comment: @ iedoc A global constants will do the same thing, but for us it is easier to set a compiler constant automatically in our build process.

Comment: @iedoc `because the swf can load in other swf's` oops misread that as SWF itself can be loaded INTO other swf's, but I think you mean the other way. As long as this [version-check] SWF itself is the parent loader then the solution is correct

Comment: @VC.One thats a good point, but we won't have the same problem by adding an item to the context menu, because even if a loaded swf for whatever reason also added things, the version should still show up

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `SharedObject` to store and retrieve the version number:

```
var sharedObject:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("versionNumber");
var versionNumber:String;
if(sharedObject.data.value)
{
    versionNumber = sharedObject.data.value;
}
else 
{
    // no version number has been set, set it here
    versionNumber = "14.06.30";
    sharedObject.data.value = versionNumber
    sharedObject.flush();
}
```

If you have a `SharedObject` reader (I recommend [.minerva](http://blog.coursevector.com/minerva)) You can retrieve the set value without even opening the swf. Just open the `.sol` file.

For SWFs, `.sol` files are stored in `C:\Users\[USER-NAME]\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects\[random sequence of characters]`

Comment: It's a good solution, but the end user can disable the ability of your app to store sharedObjects so it may not be reliable.